# How do I assign index entries found using matlab ismember to another array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vector, assign

I have two vectors P and D. I have written the following code which looks at each element of D and then finds the same element in P (both have same elements just in different order) and returns the index of that element in P. The following code is able to do that.

```
for i=1:17
 ind = find(ismember(P,D(i)));
 ind 
 msgbox(sprintf('\n i is: %d\n',ind));
end
```

The problem is that I want each 'ind' value to be stored in an array.

```
for i=1:17
 ind(i) = find(ismember(P,D(i))); 
 msgbox(sprintf('\n i is: %d\n',ind));
end
```

returns an error.

Is it possible assign find(ismember) to different entries of an array?

Thanks!

Edited:

My vectors P and D look as follows:

```
P = {'Fz' 'Fp1' 'Cz' 'T3' 'T4'}
D = {'T4' 'Cz' 'T3' 'Fp1' 'Fz'}
```

The error I'm getting at the moment is: 
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Comment: what are the dimensions of your data? Are they just plain vectors? What do you expect to find, single or multiple occurrences for each i? If you expect to find a variable number of occurences that might be the reason there is an error. What is the error that you're getting right now?

Comment: I'll add this info into my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to implement this yourself, `ismember` can already do it:

```
P = {'Fz' 'Fp1' 'Cz' 'T3' 'T4'};
D = {'T4' 'Cz' 'T3' 'Fp1' 'Fz'};

[~, ind] = ismember(D, P)
```

results in

```
ind =

     5     3     4     2     1
```

But if you really want to do it yourself – your code basically works already

```
ind = zeros(size(D));
for i = 1 : numel(D)
    ind(i) = find(ismember(P, D(i)));
end
```

and gives the same result.

Comment: You have no idea how many hours I spent trying to get the right thing.. arhhhhhh. Thanks so much!! With the second part I get an error that says 'Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.' but since the first part does it, its fine. Thanks a bunch!!